# Give me regex for finding account number in bunch of converted text documents from bank statement pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, pdftotext

I have bunch of different bank statement pdf's which I have converted to text from which consumer information is to be extracted. I have to write regex for extracting out account number. The account number is followed by specific keywords such as:

```
account number,
account no,
a/c no
```

I will paste some sample text containing this info.

Sample 1:

```
"bank of india  account statement name abcd account no. 123456 account type savings account"
```

Sample 2:

```
"statement for a/c no 11111111 between 16-09-2019 and 16-03-2020"
```

Sample 3:

```
"shyam alaspure<br />
period<br />
01-12-2019 to 29-02-2020<br />
cust.reln.no<br />
XXXXXXXX<br />
account no<br />
9XXX99999"<br />
```

I have used following regex

```
'account no.\s*([^.]+|\S+)'
```

but output gives all text after account no.

Please help me out finding the solution.

Comment: Got the answer regex should be `r'account no.\s+((?:\w+(?:|$)){1})'`

Comment: So, what you have is `account no.\s+(\w+)`. But it looks like it only matches the first input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

- `(?:|$)` is always matching an empty string, this pattern is redundant
- `{1}` is always redundant, never use it in manually written regexps
- `.` used outside of character classes matches any char but a line break char, always escape it, `\.`, to match a literal char. `[.]` also matches a literal dot.

You can use

```
r'\b(?:a/c|account) no\.?\s+(\w+)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5bOrYd/2)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:a/c|account)`  - either `a/c` or `account`
- `no.?` - space, `no`, an optional dot
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more letters, digits or underscores

Comment: Thanks a lot before this I was saving patterns in list and applying to the text.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below regex

```
(?i)(?:a\/c|account)\s*no\.?\s+(\w+)
```

see it working [here](https://regex101.com/r/TQyb20/1/)

Comment: It is my regex suggestion, no need to copy.